# CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call

Tags: pytorch

Just for study, I just tried to run the code below.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dFC0FL-521m7CL_PSd8RLKq67jgTJVhL?usp=sharing

But there's an error "CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1."

Details are in the picture.

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?